# How can I get the data from only October in my dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe over multiple years of data. But I only want the data from October. I tried this via a query but this would not help. here is my code:

```py
query_1 = 'SELECT "Movie ID", Date, Gross FROM daily'

query_2 = 'SELECT "Movie ID", Genre FROM movies'

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(query_1)

Daily_gross = pd.read_sql_query(query_1, conn)

Movies = pd.read_sql_query(query_2, conn)

df_q1 = pd.merge(Daily_gross, Movies)

df_q1_Horror = df_q1[df_q1.Genre == 'Horror']

df_q1_Horror
```

Comment: Please use a WHERE clause for  month.  'SELECT "Movie ID", Date, Gross FROM daily WHERE DATEPART(month, Date) = 10'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with list comprehension, assuming that your *Date* column is already in `DateTime` format

`df_oct = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[i] for i, x in enumerate(df.Date) if x.month == 10])`